# Cron job & logger commands

Tags: bash, cron, logging

I have a backup cron job that `rsync` files between 2 locations. To get some logged output that it has run, the job has this syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

logger "Seafile File System Backup Started"

rsync -apz /mnt/data/SeafileData /mnt/data/backups/seafile
rsync -apz /mnt/data/SeafileFiles /mnt/data/backups/seafile

logger "Seafile File System Backup Finished"
```

However, looking back into the `syslog` at the time the job executes, the only entry for "seafile" in here is the cron entry:

> Jan 23 13:00:01 host CRON[10474]: (user) CMD
> (/mnt/data/backup/seafileFileSystem.sh)

Can anyone provide corrections to this please?

Comment: What is your rsyslog configuration? The default syslog facility/severity for the `logger` command is `user.notice`. Maybe messages of that facility/severity are logged elsewhere or not logged at all?

Comment: It could be a problem with your script or the output from the script might tell you why it's not working. Do you log or have you checked the scripts output? If not log the output somewhere like a cron job of: `* * * * * /path/to/my/script.bash >> /path/to/my/log.log 2>&1`